# Use the data rendered in output through DT::renderDataTable for further plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dt

I have developed a `shiny app`, in which I am uploading a number of CSV files in each tab.  After performing some mathematical operations on the uploaded data, I am getting N number of data tables as an output. I am rendering those data tables using `DT::renderDataTable`.
Now, let say I have 3 different `datatables`  rendered using `DT::renderDataTable` I want to use the output rendered in those datatables to plot a combined graph. (3 `geom_line()` on top of each other)

This is how I am rendering the data in the datatable:

```
output$Data_FSC <- DT::renderDataTable({
          x1 <- data2()[, c(input$xcol2, input$ycol2)]
          M <- x1
          #calculate rotation angle
          alpha <- -atan((M[1,2]-tail(M,1)[,2])/(M[1,1]-tail(M,1)[,1]))
          #rotation matrix
          rotm <- matrix(c(cos(alpha),sin(alpha),-sin(alpha),cos(alpha)),ncol=2)
          #shift, rotate, shift back
          M2 <- t(rotm %*% (t(M)-c(M[1,1],M[1,2]))+c(M[1,1],M[1,2]))
          M2[nrow(M2),2] <- M2[1,2]
          M2
          
          d_f3 <- data.frame(x = M2[,1], y = (M2[,2]-min(M2[1,2])))
          
          v_f1 <- subset(d_f3,  y > ((input$below2)/1000) & y < ((input$above2)/1000), select = c(x,y))
          
          fla_upper2 <- lm(formula = y+((input$Upper_Poly_Limit2)/1000000) ~ poly(x,input$degree2, raw = TRUE), v_f1)
          fla_lower2 <- lm(formula = y-((input$Lower_Poly_Limit2)/1000000) ~ poly(x,input$degree2, raw = TRUE), v_f1)
          
          v_f1$upper2 <- predict(fla_upper2, newdata=v_f1)
          v_f1$lower2 <- predict(fla_lower2, newdata=v_f1)
          
          v_f1$region2 <- ifelse(v_f1[,2] <= v_f1$upper2 & v_f1[,2] >= v_f1$lower2, 'inside', 'outside')
          
          kl <- subset(v_f1, region2 =='inside')
          
          g <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
            geom_smooth(data = kl, aes_string(kl[,1], kl[,2]), formula = y ~ poly(x,input$degree_2, raw = TRUE), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 0.5)
          
          r <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]
          q <- data.frame(x = r[,1], y = r[,2])
          
          #calculate rotation angle
          beta <- -atan((q[1,2]-tail(q,1)[,2])/(q[1,1]-tail(q,1)[,1]))
          #rotation matrix
          rot_m <- matrix(c(cos(beta),sin(beta),-sin(beta),cos(beta)),ncol=2)
          #shift, rotate, shift back
          M_2 <- t(rot_m %*% (t(q)-c(q[1,1],q[1,2]))+c(q[1,1],q[1,2]))
          M_2[nrow(M_2),2] <- M_2[1,2]
          M_2
          
          M_3 <- data.frame(x= (M_2[,1]-median(M_2[,1])), y= (M_2[,2]-min(M_2[,2])))
          the_data <- reactive(M_3)
          the_data()
        })
```

I tried feeding the output of the `DT::renderDataTable` as input for `ggplot` but my shiny app is showing me an error saying that

> Reading from `shinyoutput` object is not allowed.

I already knew that 'Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed'.
I just want to know whether there is any way I can use the output rendered in datatable for further plotting in a shiny app.

Comment: It's difficult to make a suggestion without seeing your code.  How are you generating your tables?  I would advise against generating directly in the `renderDataTable()` function for your output and use a reactive function to generate your datatables.  You can then call that function and utilize the data for creation of the `renderPlot()` elsewhere.

Comment: ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating what I think you want to do.

Notice the separation of data from presentation: `t1`, `t2` and `t3` are reactives representing your CSV files.  Each is rendered in a different data table.  `allData` is a reactive containing union of the CSV data.  This is used as the source data for the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("n", "Number of points:", min=2, max=20, value=10),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  dataTableOutput("table1"),
  dataTableOutput("table2"),
  dataTableOutput("table3")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  t1 <- reactive({ tibble(x=1:input$n, y=rnorm(input$n), key="Table 1") })
  t2 <- reactive({ tibble(x=1:input$n, y=rnorm(input$n), key="Table 2") })
  t3 <- reactive({ tibble(x=1:input$n, y=rnorm(input$n), key="Table 3") })
  allData <- reactive({ bind_rows(t1(), t2(), t3()) })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({ t1() })
  output$table2 <- renderDT({ t2() })
  output$table3 <- renderDT({ t3() })
  output$plot <-renderPlot({ allData() %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=key)) })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It might be worth looking at using [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) to manage and present the CSV files.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. But, can you explain the purpose of numericInput here?

Comment: It has no direct relevance to your problem.  I just wanted a simple means to trigger a change to the input data to demonstrate the reactivity of the outputs.  Apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Now, the only thing I want different is, I want to bind_cols, so did it this way: allData <- reactive({bind_cols(the_data1(), the_data2(), the_data3())}). Now I want to plot by selecting different columns of that reactive dataframe called 'allData'. How do I access a particular column and provide them as an input for ggplot?

Comment: You can regard a reacive as a function that returns a value and which automatically reruns whenever any of its input change.  In this case, `allData()` returns a tibble.  So `allData()$myCol` is the column `myCol` inside the `allData()` tibble.  By the way, the fact that you are column binding rather than row binding suggests to me that your data may not be [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  If so, I advise you to reconsider.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I will do it with bind_rows. I realized that this is what I want to do. Just ignore my previous comment about using bind_cols.